# How to click on button when <input type =Button> using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors, getelementbyid

How to click on button when input type is button , I am using below code, click on button is not working?

```
<p>
<img class="getdata-button" style="float:right;" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" id="get" onclick="document.getElementById('submitMe').click()">  
<input type="button" value="Get Results" tabindex="9" id="submitMe" onclick="submitData();" style="display:none" ;="">
</p>
```

I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[@type='button']")).click()
driver.find_element_by_id("get").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("submitMe").click()
```

also used xpath for both still nothing

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean by "click on button is not working". Is there some error that occurs?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through JavaScript if that is acceptable for you:

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('submitMe').click()")`

The `<img>` element fires an `onclick` event: `onclick="document.getElementById('submitMe').click()"`; it locates and clicks the `<input>` element button below in the DOM. The Selenium click interaction can be skipped and call the same JavaScript from the `<img>` element which should get you the desired result.